# how to sync cookies between android.webkit.CookieManager and java.net.HttpUrlConnection on Android

Tags: android, synchronization, httpcookie, cookiemanager

I'm making a progam on Android.
It has one button and one WebView. If I click the button, It send post message to a web server. (using httpurlconnection)
The webview load a page from the same server. I want to sync cookies between core and webview. I found the method from core to webview. But, I couln't find a method from webview to core.

I tried these order.

1. the page of webview is loaded.
2. read cookies from webview.
3. add these cookies to core cookies using HttpCookie.

   URI uri = new URI(url);

   HttpCookie httpCookie = new HttpCookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());

   ((java.net.CookieManager) CookieHandler.getDefault()).getCookieStore().add(uri, httpCookie);

but It doesn't working. what is wrong? please advice me about it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the cookie to your HttpPost object as well, try this:

```
httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=" + httpCookie.getValue());
```

where httpPost is an instance of org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost